# Symlinks not working from Explorer but work fine from cmd shell

Tags: windows, symlink-traversal

I'm seeing a weird behaviour for one user in a network. They cannot follow some symlinks we have configured on the file server.
If I open a command shell I can open the symlinked folder without problems. I can also cd into the folder and everything appears normal. i.e fsutil behaviour is correctly set to permit symlinked folders.

We use a GPO to set the symlink following behaviour and its worked until now.

However this one user is unable to use windows explorer to follow the links.

Anyone seen similar behaviour?
Server is windows 2012 (yes I know, obsolete. Its scheduled to be upgraded), client is windows 1o pro